# How to save configuration of mysql client command line in windows 10?

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client to login to my local MySQL server. I can change the default prompt 'mysql>' to something I like. But how can I save the configuration so I don't have to configure it every time when I connect to the Server. Thank you so much!

Comment: Isn't there an INI file or section for the client? Off topic.

Comment: How do you change the prompt to begin with? Why not just put those commands in a batch file?

Comment: 1. There is an INI file. But after I add one entry of 'MYSQL_PS1="\u@\h(\d)" in C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini... The server has trouble to boot up. If I restore the original INI it works fine again. Apparently, something wrong with my entry. Not sure how to fix it.                             2. Regarding a batch file, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Batch file not necessary, create a [system environment variable](https://imgbox.com/eLxZghBH). Note the 5 steps.

Answer (score 1):

@everyone

Use an option file. You can set the prompt option in the [mysql] group of any MySQL option file,
such as `/etc/my.cnf`
or the `dbserver/.my.cnf`

or  `dbserver/my.ini` file in your home directory. For example:

in the file, you insert the code:

```
[mysql]
prompt=(\\u@\\h) [\\d]>\\_
```

### See more here:[documetation mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html#:%7E:text=Use%20an%20option%20file.%20You%20can%20set%20the%20prompt%20option%20in%20the%20%5Bmysql%5D%20group%20of%20any%20MySQL%20option%20file%2C%20such%20as%20/etc/my.cnf%20or%20the%20.my.cnf%20file%20in%20your%20home%20directory.%20For%20example%3A)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MMaR.png)